# OpenSSL .NET wrapper adding classes and methods

Tags: c#, .net, openssl

I downloaded the OpenSSL .NET wrapper on Visual C# 2010 express edition and I tried to modify the source code by adding methods and classes in the Crypto library. Then I compiled it and generate new ManagedOpenSSL.DLL.
I made a test program and i put this DLL as a reference to check if my modifications were done.
The result is that I found my new methods (I added them to an existing classes) exist, but my new classes does not exist. 
Does some one know why ? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget to put `public` in front of your classes?

```
public class MyNewClass
{
}
```

Comment: of yeah sure how stupid iam, i was focusing on complexed problems that I forget that ^^ thank you very much.

Comment: the easiest problems are the hardest to find, since we always tend to believe that problems always are complex :)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any of the code you added, I can only guess that either you added `internal` classes and thus they cannot be seen, you are not looking in the correct namespace for your classes, or in fact you added no classes at all. Again, without your code, these are only guesses.